# Terraform Azure assign security rules to different security groups

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I create three network security groups with "for_each" loop, and I want to assign them security rules. My aim is to assign different security rules to different security groups, f.e. "allow-pgadmin-traffic" should be assigned only to the db-nsg.

main.tf:

```
# Create network security group for worker VMs 
  resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "nsg" {
  for_each            = toset(var.vm_names)      
  name                = "${each.value}-nsg"
  #name                = var.net_sg_db_name
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name #var.rg_name

  dynamic "security_rule" {
    for_each = var.nsg_rules
    content {
      name = security_rule.value["name"]
      priority = security_rule.value["priority"]
      direction = security_rule.value["direction"]
      access = security_rule.value["access"]
      protocol = security_rule.value["protocol"]
      source_port_range = security_rule.value["source_port_range"]
      destination_port_range = security_rule.value["destination_port_range"]
      source_address_prefix = security_rule.value["source_address_prefix"]
      destination_address_prefix = security_rule.value["destination_address_prefix"]
    }

  }
  }
```

variables.tf:

```
variable "nsg_rules" {
  type = list(object({
    name = string
    priority = number
    direction = string
    access = string
    protocol = string
    source_port_range = string
    destination_port_range = string
    source_address_prefix = string
    destination_address_prefix = string
  }))
  description = "The values for each NSG rule"
}
variable "db_nsg_rules" {
    type        = list(string)
    description = "The db network security group rules"
    default = ["allow-ssh", "allow-http-all", "allow-https-all", "allow-ping", "allow-postgreSql-traffic", "allow-pgadmin-traffic"]
}

variable "dataanalysis_nsg_rules" {
    type        = list(string)
    description = "The dataanalysis netork security group rules"
    default = ["allow-ssh", "allow-http-all", "allow-https-all", "allow-ping", "allow-2223-traffic", "allow-80-89-traffic", "allow-90-99-traffic", "allow-5601-traffic", "allow-3000-traffic"]
}

variable "dataengineering_nsg_rules" {
    type        = list(string)
    description = "The dataengineering netork security group rules"
    default = ["allow-ssh", "allow-http-all", "allow-https-all", "allow-ping", "allow-superset-traffic", "allow-kafka1-traffic", "allow-kafka2-traffic", "allow-kafka3-traffic", "allow-kafka4-traffic", "allow-kafka5-traffic"]
}
```

terraform.tfvars: (I just put some security groups, not all of them)

```
nsg_rules = [ 
    {
    #Allow SSH traffic from public subnet to private subnet.
    name                       = "allow-ssh"
    priority                   = 100
    direction                  = "Inbound"
    access                     = "Allow"
    protocol                   = "Tcp"
    source_port_range          = "*"
    destination_port_range     = "22"
    source_address_prefix      = "10.0.2.0/24"
    destination_address_prefix = "*"
  },
  {
#Allow http traffic from private subnet to Internet
    name                       = "allow-http-all"
    priority                   = 110
    direction                  = "Outbound"
    access                     = "Allow" 
    protocol                   = "Tcp"
    source_port_range          = "*"
    destination_port_range     = "80"
    source_address_prefix      = "*"
    destination_address_prefix = "*"
  },
{
    # Allow traffic from PostgreSql port 5432 to database-sg.
    name                       = "allow-postgreSql-traffic"
    priority                   = 140
    direction                  = "Inbound"
    access                     = "Allow"
    protocol                   = "Tcp"
    source_port_range          = "*"
    destination_port_range     = "5432"
    source_address_prefix      = "*"
    destination_address_prefix = "*"
  },
 {
# Allow pgadmin to database-sg.
    name                       = "allow-pgadmin-traffic"
    priority                   = 150
    direction                  = "Inbound"
    access                     = "Allow"
    protocol                   = "Tcp"
    source_port_range          = "*"
    destination_port_range     = "8080"
    source_address_prefix      = "*"
    destination_address_prefix = "*"
  },
{
  # Allow traffic from port 5601 to dataanalysis.
    name                       = "allow-5601-traffic"
    priority                   = 200
    direction                  = "Inbound"
    access                     = "Allow"
    protocol                   = "Tcp"
    source_port_range          = "*"
    destination_port_range     = "5601"
    source_address_prefix      = "*"
    destination_address_prefix = "*"
    
  },
{
  # Allow kafka1 traffic to dataengineering.
    name                       = "allow-kafka1-traffic"
    priority                   = 230
    direction                  = "Inbound"
    access                     = "Allow"
    protocol                   = "Tcp"
    source_port_range          = "*"
    destination_port_range     = "9200"
    source_address_prefix      = "*"
    destination_address_prefix = "*" 
  },
{
   # Allow kafka2 traffic to dataengineering.
    name                       = "allow-kafka2-traffic"
    priority                   = 240
    direction                  = "Inbound"
    access                     = "Allow"
    protocol                   = "Tcp"
    source_port_range          = "*"
    destination_port_range     = "9300"
    source_address_prefix      = "*"
    destination_address_prefix = "*" 
  }
]
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: I'm not getting any error. With this current configuration I assign all security rules to all network security groups. And I would like to assign only some rules, that I want, to the security groups.

Comment: So simple just remove the NSG names from default of respective rules  . So it won't add the rule for NSG.

Comment: The point is, I actually want add only the default rules to the NSG, no other ones.

Comment: Can you please show me the output for an example